# como enviar un mail en java web con la libreria javax.mail.jar

Tags: java, jsp, java-ee, servlets, javamail

Estoy utilizando jsp,  servlet y clases en java para enviar un mail a partir de un formulario, funciona en el pc de modo local utilizando [payara](/questions/tagged/payara) 4.1 y [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) de un correo gmail a otro pero cuando subo la aplicación a un *host* de java no envía el correo.

Tengo la aplicación en el *host*

```
www.blancopropiedades.cl/pruebaJavaMail/
```

**Servlet:**

```
Email email = new Email();
boolean resultado = email.enviarCorreo(mensaje, asunto);
```

clase en java:

```
public class Email {

public boolean enviarCorreo(String mensaje, String asunto){
    boolean enviado = false;
        try{
            String de = "correode@gmail.com"; String clave = 
            "contraseña";
            String para="para@gmail.com";  
            String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

            Properties prop = System.getProperties();

            prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
            prop.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
            prop.put("mail.smtp.user",de);
            prop.put("mail.smtp.password", clave);
            prop.put("mail.smtp.port",587);
            prop.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");

            Session sesion = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop,null);

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(sesion);

            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(de));

            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new 
            InternetAddress(para));

            message.setSubject(asunto);
            message.setText(mensaje);

            Transport transport = sesion.getTransport("smtp");

            transport.connect(host,de,clave);

            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

            transport.close();

            enviado = true;

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return enviado;
}
```

Comment: voy a tratar de ayudarte en tu problema. Si tu código está funcionando en tu PC, en un localhost significa que funciona. El problema puede llegar a ser que no tengas abierto el puerto 587 en tu host, y eso evita que salgan los correo. Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar Spring Boot o bajar directamente la librería. Esto lo he usado recientemente en mi aplicación web y funciona muy bien, Lo que tienes es que en el caso de Gmail permitir que aplicaciones clientes puedan enviar y recibir correo, sino te rechazara la conexión remota.

dependencia

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

luego aqui tienes un codigo: Tomado de baeldung

```
public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
JavaMailSender mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
mailSender.setPort(587);

mailSender.setUsername("my.gmail@gmail.com");
mailSender.setPassword("password");

Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");

return mailSender;
}
```

Luego lo envias:

```
public void sendSimpleMessage(
  String to, String subject, String text) {
    ...
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage(); 
    message.setTo(to); 
    message.setSubject(subject); 
    message.setText(text);
    emailSender.send(message);
    ...
}
```

mas informacion puedes revisar este link:
[Spring email. Configuraciones](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-email)